# Taylor's remainder for function of two variables

Tags: taylor-expansion

I am deriving the formula for Taylor's remainder in 2 dimensions. I think that I have understood something wrong. Let f(x, y) be a function of two variables. First, I have thought it as a one variable function, where y is constant.

Then it can be written as follows:
$$ f\left(x{,}\ y\right)=\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{1}{i!}\frac{\partial^if\left(x_0{,}\ y\right)}{\partial x^i}\cdot\left(x-x_0\right)^i+\frac{1}{\left(n+1\right)!}\frac{\partial^{n+1}f\left(\zeta_1{,}\ y\right)}{\partial x^{n+1}}\cdot\left(x-x_0\right)^{n+1}, \ \zeta_1 \in [x, \ x_0] \ \mathrm{or} \ \in [x_0, \ x] $$

Now let's consider x a constant:
$$ \begin{align}
f(x, y) &=\sum_{j=0}^m\frac{1}{j!}\frac{\partial^j}{\partial y^j}\left(\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{1}{i!}\frac{\partial^if\left(x_0{,}\ y_0\right)}{\partial x^i}\cdot\left(x-x_0\right)^i+\frac{1}{\left(n+1\right)!}\frac{\partial^{n+1}f\left(\zeta_1{,}\ y_0\right)}{\partial x^{n+1}}\cdot\left(x-x_0\right)^{n+1}\right)\cdot\left(y-y_0\right)^j \\
&+\frac{1}{\left(m+1\right)!}\frac{\partial^{m+1}}{\partial y^{m+1}}\left(\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{1}{i!}\frac{\partial^if\left(x_0{,}\ \zeta_2\right)}{\partial x^i}\cdot\left(x-x_0\right)^i+\frac{1}{\left(n+1\right)!}\frac{\partial^{n+1}f\left(\zeta_1{,}\ \zeta_2\right)}{\partial x^{n+1}}\cdot\left(x-x_0\right)^{n+1}\right)\cdot\left(y-y_0\right)^{m+1} \\
&= \sum_{j=0}^m\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{1}{i!j!}\frac{\partial^j}{\partial y^j}\frac{\partial^if\left(x_0{,}\ y_0\right)}{\partial x^i}\cdot\left(x-x_0\right)^i\left(y-y_0\right)^j+\sum_{j=0}^m\frac{1}{\left(n+1\right)!j!}\frac{\partial^j}{\partial y^j}\frac{\partial^{n+1}f\left(\zeta_1{,}\ y_0\right)}{\partial x^{n+1}}\cdot\left(x-x_0\right)^{n+1}\left(y-y_0\right)^j \\
&+\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{1}{i!\left(m+1\right)!}\frac{\partial^{m+1}}{\partial y^{m+1}}\frac{\partial^if\left(x_0{,}\ \zeta_2\right)}{\partial x^i}\cdot\left(x-x_0\right)^i\left(y-y_0\right)^{m+1}+\frac{1}{\left(n+1\right)!\left(m+1\right)!}\frac{\partial^{m+1}}{\partial y^{m+1}}\frac{\partial^{n+1}f\left(\zeta_1{,}\ \zeta_2\right)}{\partial x^{n+1}}\cdot\left(x-x_0\right)^{n+1}\left(y-y_0\right)^{m+1} \\
&=\sum_{j=0}^m\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{1}{i!j!}\frac{\partial^{i+j}f\left(x_0{,}\ y_0\right)}{\partial y^j\partial x^i}\cdot\left(x-x_0\right)^i\left(y-y_0\right)^j+\underline{\sum_{j=0}^m\frac{1}{\left(n+1\right)!j!}\frac{\partial^{n+1+j}f\left(\zeta_1{,}\ y_0\right)}{\partial y^j\partial x^{n+1}}\cdot\left(x-x_0\right)^{n+1}\left(y-y_0\right)^j} \\
&+ \underline{\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{1}{i!\left(m+1\right)!}\frac{\partial^{i+m+1}f\left(x_0{,}\ \zeta_2\right)}{\partial y^{m+1}\partial x^i}\cdot\left(x-x_0\right)^i\left(y-y_0\right)^{m+1}+\frac{1}{\left(n+1\right)!\left(m+1\right)!}\frac{\partial^{n+1+m+1}f\left(\zeta_1{,}\ \zeta_2\right)}{\partial y^{m+1}\partial x^{n+1}}\cdot\left(x-x_0\right)^{n+1}\left(y-y_0\right)^{m+1}}
\end{align} $$

So here the underlined part is my suggestion for the remainder. Can someone tell me what went wrong?